# How to crop and save an image underneath a div with a clip-path in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, clip

Basically, I'm working on a freelance project right now where an image is uploaded on a website and is clipped on a path that is already defined. I'll give you an example:

[image]

As you can see, I placed the `img` tag just underneath a `div` tag

```
<div style="clip-path: xxx">
    <img src="xxxxx.xxx">
</div>
```

Now, I used the JQuery UI Draggable widget to move the image around. Got that covered, no problems there.

The problem is, how do I capture and save that image? I tried using [Html2Canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) to 'screenshot' it but it kept resulting in a square instead of a heart image.

Comment: `clip-path` property is for viewing purposes only, it doesn't have an effect to the actual content. You've to crop the image in a canvas instead.

Comment: @Teemu Oh, I see. Thanks for your input. Any suggestions on JavaScript widgets that can implement that?

Comment: No widgets needed, the cropping ability is built in [drawImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) method.

Comment: @Teemu Kiitos paljon!

Comment: Hmm ... I didn't read the question carefully enough, you can't crop an image to heart shape with drawImage. It's not even possible, images are always rectangles.